# sqlite query to select new items with no history

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, networking

I have an addrwatch database (https://github.com/fln/addrwatch) that has a database similar to :

```
1381347053|eth0|0|20:XX:XX:XX:XX:a9|192.168.1.108|0
1381347056|eth0|0|00:XX:XX:XX:XX:02|192.168.1.138|0
1381347066|eth0|0|f4:XX:XX:XX:XX:39|192.168.1.152|0
1381347093|eth0|0|00:XX:XX:XX:XX:27|192.168.1.157|0
1381347112|eth0|0|00:XX:XX:XX:XX:20|192.168.1.104|0
1381347132|eth0|0|00:XX:XX:XX:XX:cc|192.168.1.107|0
1381347142|eth0|0|00:XX:XX:XX:XX:0b|192.168.1.5|0
```

I want to return all items where:

- the mac address is seen within the last 24 hours
- the mac address wasnt seen more than 24 hours ago

since addrwatch puts entries for every activity of a mac address, just searching the last 24 hours will return all active network devices. I'd like to list only devices that have been introduced to the network within the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mac FROM t WHERE mac NOT IN (
    SELECT mac FROM t WHERE time < CAST(STRFTIME('%s', 'NOW', '-1 DAY') AS INTEGER)
);
```

Comment: after trying both proposed solutions, your query returned more correct results. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT mac
  FROM Table1
 WHERE mac IN(
              SELECT DISTINCT mac 
                FROM Table1
               WHERE date(time, 'unixepoch') = date('now')
             )
   AND mac NOT IN (
                   SELECT DISTINCT mac
                     FROM Table1
                    WHERE date(time, 'unixepoch') <= date('now', '-1 day')
                  )
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d56f2/3) on SqlFiddle.

Comment: thanks for the help, it seems ls_dev's query returned more rows, not quite sure what the subtle differences are

Comment: My query is returning data based on today minus all mac addresses present in the previous days. LS_dev query is based on the current time and the last 24 hours from Now

Comment: Note your condition `mac IN (...)` is redundant. You can remove it keeping same query results.